# Flask - Adding variables to another route's response?

Tags: python, flask

Say I have a route like this, that renders `lol.html` with `b` set to None:

```
@app.route('/foo/')
def foo():
    return render_template('lol.html', a='a', b=None)
```

I want to make another route, that can intercept one route and add some variables to it before returning. Something like this:

```
@app.route('/bar/')
def bar():
    intercepted = make_response(foo())
    # do something signficant to extend the logic of foo
    flask.add_var_to_resp(intercepted, b='b')
```

How should this be accomplished in flask?

---

@jsbueno, I'm adding this to clarify your answer, which I cannot do in a comment:

```
@app.route('/foo/')
def foo(renderer=render_template):
    return renderer('foo.html', a='a')

@app.route('/bar/')
def bar():
    def renderer(template, *args, **kwargs):
        return render_template(template, *args, b='b', **kwargs)
    return foo(renderer)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adding variables to another route's response". Do you mean that render the template with the new variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask is mostly pure Python, with very little magic - so there are a series of strategies you can use.

Maybe the simplest is to have the primary view to accept optional
function arguments, and call that one from your extended views:

```
@app.route('/foo/')
def foo(b=None):
    return render_template('lol.html', a='a', b=b)

@app.route('/bar/')
def bar():
    return foo(b="b")
```

**update**:
If you don't want the original view to incorporate the extensions logic, you have to keep in mind that views returns a rendered template, that is not extensible - you can't simply add more lines inside the  `foo` view.

One alternative is to turn the renderer itself into a lazy object - that delays the call to flask actual `render_template` so that it is modifiable. For a simple view to keep working withoug bein aware of this modified render_template, it could opionally receive the renderer as a parameter.

So,

```
@app.route('/foo/')
def foo(renderer=render_template):
    return renderer('lol.html', a='a')


@app.route('/bar/')
def bar():
    def renderer(template, *args, **kw):
        return render_template(template, *args, b="b", **kw)
    return foo(renderer)
```

Should work for you - you can make the "renderer" be a smarter object where you can plug more things as needed.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have to incorporate the extension logic inside the view that I want to extend, as opposed to the extending view itself.

Comment: Great idea! Two points - I don't understand the `render_hub`, and it looks like you have a bug in line 3. I've edited my answer with a slightly reworked version of your solution that works. Would you please edit your answer before I mark this as the solution?

Comment: actually that line is uneeded, and was just dangling from a previous version. I removed it now,